# Campo tipo TEXT no toma el tipo de html &ntilde; o &aacute; para acentuación y letras Ñ

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

En mi actual trabajo, habían migrado la base de datos hecha en *MySQL* pero cuando la volvieron a montar los acentos y ñ estaban dañados, corregí los campos tipo *string* de las tablas a base de *update* con los formatos *HTML* `&aacute;`, `&eacute` (por ejemplo), pero al momento de corregir los campos tipo *text* me los retornan de la misma manera cuando consulto, un ejemplo sería: **condici&oacuten medica requiere ciruj&iacutea**.

Comment: No debiste haber hecho esos cambios, no es que _"los acentos y ñ estén dañados"_ , el problema es por el juego de caracteres usado en tus tablas, seguramente no coincide con el resto elementos de tu proyecto (html, php, etc.). Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base/59510#59510) para solucionar el problema.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir como estas imprimiendo los datos en los `input` y cual es el valor exacto de la variable que tiene en la DB?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con el juego de carácteres **utf8mb4_general_ci** o **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**, **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** se basa en el estándar **Unicode** para la clasificación y comparación, que clasifica con precisión en una amplia gama de idiomas.

Personalmente uso (**utf8_unicode_ci**).